# Spring Boot additional servlet registration

Tags: java, spring-boot, servlets, ckfinder, ckfinder3

I have a Spring Boot Web MVC application, that sits at the root of the application. I am trying to add a third party servlet ([CKFinder Java connector](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckfinder/ckfinder3-java/latest/guides/configuration.html)) to this application.

I have achieved this with the following:

```
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean<CKFinderServlet> registerCkFinder() {
        ServletRegistrationBean<CKFinderServlet> bean =
                new ServletRegistrationBean<>(new CKFinderServlet(), "/ckfinder/*");
        bean.setLoadOnStartup(-1);
        bean.setInitParameters(
                Map.of("scan-path", "<package name>"));
        bean.setMultipartConfig(new MultipartConfigElement("/tmp/upload"));
        return bean;
    }
```

The main website continues to work correctly, but when I try and hit the CKFinder servlet, I get a series of errors that show initialisation issues while errors while trying to evaluate `@Value(...)` parameters while auto-wiring my interceptors and controllers (I don't fully understand why it is constructing the controllers).

Having done some investigation, I get the feeling its to do with application contexts!? I do want to share some context information (such as the security information, logged in user etc), but I otherwise don't really need any of the other Spring MVC goodness while executing the servlet.

My question is threefold:

1. Am I right in thinking its to do with contexts?
2. How do I register the servlet such that it when called the `@Value()` and other Spring stuff evaluates correctly?
   OR
3. How do I register the servlet with a new context such that it doesn't inherit, and try to initialise, all the Spring MVC components?

I am also considering putting a controller wrapper around the servlet, but that seems overkill for something that should "just work".

Comment: A wild guess, could you comment out `registerCKFinder` and use the annotation `@ComponentScan` as shown in 3.1 [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-component-scanning)?

Comment: I mean something like this in your app:
`@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.cksource.ckfinder")
@Configuration
public class MyApp`

Comment: Seems not ... sadly (and I'm not an expert), it looks like `CKFinderServlet` class is not appropriately annotated. Making that change did cause it to pick up the config class and other components, but not the servlet itself.

Comment: Think I've solved the problem, the package I was specified in this line:
`bean.setInitParameters(Map.of("scan-path", "<package name>"));`

Was too high-level. It seems the servlet causes does an explicit scan for components in the scan path, so it was picking up all my Spring components.